# Цикл. Pyrogram (Python). С планированием задач

Tags: python, python-3.x, schedule, pyrogram

Хочу написать Юзер-бота. Использовал Pyrogram. Суть в чем, в некоторое заранее выбранное время он должен в нужный чат отправить нужное сообщение от моего имени... Свои наработки предоставляю, но оно не работает (

```
from pyrogram import Client
import time
import random
import schedule


app = Client("my_account", config_file="config.ini")
@app.on_message()
def twenty():
    app.send_message("-1001290958283", "Сообщение отправленно в 12:00")

schedule.every().day.at("12:00").do(twenty)       


while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
scheduler.start()
app.run()
```

Comment: Это код чего? Как он связан с остальным текстом?

Comment: Код исполняемого файла, что я уже сделал, но он не работает, просто показываю что у меня уже есть. Возможно я допустил ошибку при написании, или ещё что...

Comment: Строчки `scheduler.start()` и `app.run()` никогда не будут выполняться, т.к. бесконечный цикл. Код с циклом засуньте в отдельный поток

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Строчки `scheduler.start()` и `app.run()` никогда не будут выполняться, т.к. выше бесконечный цикл. Код с циклом засуньте в отдельный поток

Пример:

```
import time
from threading import Thread

import schedule
from pyrogram import Client


app = Client("my_account", config_file="config.ini")
def twenty():
    app.send_message("-1001290958283", "Сообщение отправлено в 12:00")

def run():
    schedule.every().day.at("12:00").do(twenty)

    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)


Thread(target=run).start()
app.run()
```

Если сейчас schedule будет вызывать `twenty` с `@app.on_message()`, это вызовет проблему и решением будет завести отдельную функцию для schedule без декоратора, либо вручную вызвать `app.send_message`:

```
    schedule.every().day.at("12:00").do(
        app.send_message, "-1001290958283", "Сообщение отправлено в 12:00"
    )
```

Comment: Выдает ошибку TypeError: twenty() takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were given

Comment: @МаксимСамойлюк, ошибка значит, что тот, кто вызывает функцию, передает в нее 2 параметра, но у функции параметров нет. Те параметры, уверен, добавляет `app.on_message`. Уберите `@app.on_message()` из функции, это даст возможность отправки через `schedule`. Если же нужно, чтобы при получении сообщения вызывалась та функция, то сделайте еще одну функцию. Т.е. 2 функции: одна с `@app.on_message()`, вторая без для `schedule`. Есть еще вариант, я его добавлю ниже в ответ, это через прямое указание ссылки на функцию `app.send_message`

Comment: Теперь ошибок нет, премного благодарен, так как у меня низкая репутация, не могу поднять вам репутацию.

Comment: @МаксимСамойлюк, пожалуйста :)